# Android - apk-signing: entries' certificate chain is not validated & signatures w/o a timestamp

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, jarsigner

After following the procedure in [Signing your APP with the ADT plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#adt), I verified manually the signed apk ([described below in the same page](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually)) with:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

And every entry was signed properly [s and sm], but at the end this showed up:

> Warning:
>
> This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
>
> This jar contains signatures that does not include a
>   timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this
>   jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2040-01-01) or
>   after any future revocation date.

Is it better for apks uploaded to Goggle Play to have the **jar** (apk)'s entries with a validated "certificate chain" and with the signatures with a timestamp?... Why (and why doesn't the **Export** procedure achieve this)?
If it is better, what do I need to do?

The zipalign suggested at the end of that page:

```
$ zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
```

Verified everything successfully.

Comment: Is it okay to submit the apk file, if I have this warning?

Comment: @K.Sopheak I submitted mine on that month and until now, nothing was reported about the non-validated "certificate chain". I assumed that this is a very specific Java related issue which does not affect the submission.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using the Java 7 tools.  If you install and use the Java 6 tools this will go away.

Comment: I installed java 6 (using Windows 7) but gives error "Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required." etc. how to switch between java 7 and java 6 in windows 7?